# How to convert a file extension with a specific program by using Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to change the extension of a file with a specific program (Genie2000) to obtain an eye readable file. I have to change the file extension from `.cnf` to `.tka` in Genie2000 to obtain this result. 
So basically I have to open `.cnf` file in Genie 2000 and save this file with a `.tka` extension in it.
I have several files to modify. How can I do that with Python 3.x

I know, I can open this file with

```
import os
os.startfile(file)
```

but how to save it with the desired extension?

Comment: Could you clarify what a `tka` extension is for? Is it just plain text or a format for some other program?

Answer (score 0):

Some quick searching on this lead me to find the [`pbellino/CNFreader`](https://github.com/pbellino/CNFreader) python package on Github. Assuming you want to convert your `.cnf` to `.txt`, you could follow its instructions with

```
$ pip install numpy
$ git clone https://github.com/pbellino/CNFreader.git
$ cd CNFreader
$ python read_cnf.py <path_to_your_cnf_file>
```

That package also supports usage as a library which would allow you to convert it to other target formats, as long as you have a format spec.

I'll be happy to update this answer if you can clarify what a `.tka` extension is.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. TKA files are Toolkit files. They are used to export data in txt mode. But your solution is way better. Thank you